# Django ORM Query Too Slow

Tags: mysql, sql, django, performance, orm

I use this database table with more than 10000000 datas.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfYED.png)

And use query

```
SELECT mytable.project, COUNT(*) AS `total`  
FROM mytable   
WHERE (`mytable`.`date` >= '2022-04-05' AND NOT (`mytable`.`user` = 'sw_int'))   
GROUP BY `mytable`.`project`
ORDER BY `total`
```

But this takes too many time despite the use of indexes. (about 20 secs)
How can I solve this problem?

Additionally, index is like below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRxOQ.png)
This made with django.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us table and index definitions.

Comment: I use My SQL and I edit my question.

Comment: What have you tried in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of these *may* help the speed some.  I can't tell which would be best, since it depends on the distribution of the data.

```
INDEX(date, user, project)
INDEX(user, project, date)
INDEX(project, date, user)
```

Each is "covering", meaning that the query can be performed entirely in the Index's BTree; this gives some performance boost.

One of the first two may shine due to filtering on `date` or `user`.  The third may avoid the sort for `GROUP BY project`.  (The sort for `ORDER BY` is unavoidable.)

Add all three; run it.  Also do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see which index that the Optimizer decided might be best.

(In the future, please include text, not images.)